# How to count date-cycles, when one date period ends

Tags: sql-server

I have my query:

```
ID  UserGroupCode   CreateDate  Isclose     ProductID
2   1               2015-03-16    0         3216
3   4               2015-03-17    0         3221
4   5               2015-03-24    0         3216
5   6               2015-04-03    1         3216
6   7               2015-04-03    1         3216
7   8               2015-04-06    1         3215
8   9               2015-04-07    1         3215
13  14              2017-04-11    1         3216
14  15              2017-04-14    0         3216
16  6               2017-04-17    0         3221
17  16              2017-04-18    1         3215
18  17              2017-04-18    1         3221
```

Where i need to count each cycle(isClose), as you can see there two UserGroupCodes with #6, first one have IsClose 1 and another have 0, which means one cycle-period is done, and another started, i need to count the cycles, basically having new column, that shows how many cycles each usergroup have done

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: New column ''Cycles" 
   1 (where UserGroupCode is not repeating as it might ended or still continuing 1st cycle period),
   2 ( where UserGroupCode shows 6 again, as new cycle started)

Comment: Please add your expected result in a tabular format to your post

Comment: Why cant you simply add up the IsClose column and group it by UserGroupCode?

Comment: I cant just add up, as if the 2nd(and so on) cycle is not finished it wont be shown in system as 1, will still be 0 if the 2nd++ cycles aren't finished

Comment: Ok then. Why cant you just count the zeroes and group by userGroup? If you only care about a whether a cycle happened, you could simply count the starts. If not, please clarify further.

Comment: I need to count cycles for each UserGroupCode, as it links to another table, where User will check how many cycles each UserGroup has done. 

But i see logic in your words, will try and see if it works, thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand the problem correctly, you can do it with the following logic.

There are codes starting with 1 and ending with 0. (CTE1) The codes are filtered according to the given criterion. (Start 1 and end 0 CTE3)

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (Id INT, UserGroupCode INT, Isclose INT )

INSERT INTO @Tbl
VALUES  
(2  , 1 ,0),
(3  , 4 ,0),
(4  , 5 ,0),
(5  , 6 ,1),
(6  , 7 ,0),
(7  , 8 ,1),
(8  , 9 ,1),
(13 , 14,1),
(14 , 15,0),
(16 , 6 ,0),
(17 , 16,1),
(18 , 17,1)

;WITH CTE1
AS
(
    SELECT
        T.UserGroupCode
    FROM
        @Tbl T
    GROUP BY
        T.UserGroupCode HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
)
, CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT  
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.UserGroupCode ORDER BY T.Id) RowId
    FROM 
        @Tbl T
    WHERE
        t.UserGroupCode IN (SELECT * FROM CTE1)
), CTE3
AS
(
    SELECT 
        C.UserGroupCode,
        COUNT(1) CountOfRow
    FROM 
        cte2 C
    GROUP BY
        C.UserGroupCode,
        C.Isclose + C.RowId
)

SELECT 
    C.UserGroupCode,
    COUNT(1) CountOfCycle
FROM CTE3 C
WHERE
    C.CountOfRow = 2
GROUP BY
    C.UserGroupCode
```

Result:

```
UserGroupCode CountOfCycle
------------- ------------
6             1
```

Comment: can you help me out with another thing. im trying to get into logic, but my query failing, look down